# Error when importing files within breakpoint-sass mixin

Tags: sass, breakpoint-sass

I'm trying to import a set of files using breakpoint-sass but am getting an error

`filenames.scss (Line 99: Import directives may not be used within control directives or mixins.)`

The code im using is:

```
@include breakpoint($breakpoint2) {
  @import "path/to/sassfilename";
}
```

Is this even allowed? Can I import files in breakpoint? I couldn't see anything documentation to say otherwise so I'm assuming it is possible to import files instead of inlining all the css.

Answer (score 0):

You can not use **import** into **include** **mixin**. This is your error.
You have to move the import line outside conditionals or directives.

Maybe you can create a file named _breakpoint.scss and, inside it, place your code:

```
//filenames.scss
@import "breakpoint";
//some imported files

//_breakpoint.scss
@import 'path/to/sassfilename';
```

Regards.